# I'm trying to sort an Array List of strings in ABC order without using a pre-made class

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Im having trouble sorting my array list in ABC order. This is what I have so far, any ideas on how to achieve it? My output is switching some of the words, but not putting the whole array list in ABC order. I'm lost, as you can tell from my loops at the end =[

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ArrayListLab
{
   public static void main (String [] args)
   {
       Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
       ArrayList <String> words = new ArrayList <String> ();
       for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
       {
           System.out.println("Pick a word, any word!");
           words.add(scan.nextLine());
        }
       for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++)
       {
         words.get(x).compareTo(words.get(x+1));
         if (words.get(x).compareTo(words.get(x+1))>0)
         {
            String temp = words.get(x+1);
            words.set((x+1),words.get(x));
            words.set(x, temp);
         }
        else
           if (words.get(x).compareTo(words.get(x+1))<0)
           {
              words.get(x);  
           }
           else
              if(words.get(x).compareTo(words.get(x+1))==0)
              {
                  words.get(x);
              }

    }
    System.out.println(words);
}
}
```

Comment: Which sorting algorithm are you trying to implement?

Comment: What do you mean by premade class? Arraylist is "premade"

Comment: Why don't you use sort() method of collection if you are using String a type.

   Collections.sort(list);

Comment: Also, it isn't possible to sort a list in a single for loop